# to call the retrofit in different classes

Tags: java, android, generics, retrofit

I am a beginner to the android. I am using Retrofit to call the API. But I would like to write the retrofit call method only once and use the same function in different API calls in my application. I try to create It's a generic method in nonactivity class and use it in my activity class.

```
public static generic_Retrofit_Class apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static generic_Retrofit_Class getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new generic_Retrofit_Class();
    }
    return apiClient;
}


public Retrofit getclient()
{
    return getclient(null);
}

private Retrofit getclient(Object o) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okHttpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    okHttpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    okHttpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constant.Baseurl)
            .client(okHttpClient.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit;
}
```

After this code when I call this method in my Activity class it shows an error. Here is the implementation of the method in the Activity class.

```
private void Getstock() {
    final String mid = medicineid.getText().toString().trim();
    final String batch = batchno.getText().toString().trim();

    if (medicineid.getText().length() != 0 && batchno.getText().length() != 0) {
        App_Interfaces app_interfaces = (App_Interfaces) new generic_Retrofit_Class().getclient().create(App_Interfaces.class);
        Map<String, String> mapdata = new HashMap<>();
        mapdata.put("mid", mid);
        mapdata.put("batch", batch);
        final Call<Response> getstock_call = app_interfaces.getstock(mapdata);

        getstock_call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && response != null) {
                    String jsonresponse = response.body().toString();
                    parseStockData(jsonresponse);
                    System.out.print(jsonresponse);
                    return;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'retrofit2.Response' is not a valid response body type. Did you mean ResponseBody?
>   for method App_Interfaces.getstock

here is my Interface Code

```
public interface get_stock 
   {
        @GET("/getstock")
        Call<Response> getstock(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
   }
```

Comment: The call is wrapped with `Response` datatype but you missed to specify the type of response `Call<Response<T>>`. Specify your required type in the place of `T`

Comment: add app_interfaces code

Comment: @NatarajKR sir,<T> should be my POJO class or any other type.  can you clear it more, please? I have POJO classes for all activities.

Comment: Yes,`T` can be your POJO class.

Comment: ok, sir. can you please tell me that I am doing right to call. I created a generic method of the retrofit call to reduce the redundancy of code to write for each call.

Comment: sir @NatarajKR I specify my POJO class as Response type. it still showing same error message.

Comment: Your API interface code will be helpful.

Comment: @NatarajKR ok sir, I now I added the My interface code. could you check it and help me please

Comment: @ashish in your interface too, specify the POJO for Response

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO

Change the **getClient** method code as

```
public class YOUR_CLASS{

   private static YOUR_API_INTERFACE  retrofit = null;

   public static YOUR_API_INTERFACE getClient() { // no need to pass the object params

     if(retrofit == null){

         //you client code same as you written in question

         retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                     .baseUrl(Constant.Baseurl)
                     .client(okHttpClient.build()) //okHtttpClient from your client code
                     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                     .build();

      }
      return retrofit.create(YOUR_API_INTERFACE.class);
   }
}
```

Now, you can easily access the retrofit api interface by `YOUR_CLASS.getClient()`. This will return your **Retrofit Interface**

Your Retrofit Interface with declare method should be like this

```
public interface YOUR_API_INTERFACE {
   @GET("your api name")
   Call<YOUR_POJO> yourApi();
}
```

In your activity/fragment class you can access the yourApi method as

```
YOUR_CLASS.getClient().yourApi();
```

Comment: can you please make it some more clear about that static variable retrofit = null. why this is done. could you please explain it

Comment: Well, that is for memory management, you read the explanation here https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java
the single static variable of retrofit will be share across all instance/objects of YOUR_CLASS

Comment: ok sir.. Thank you. I have one more confusion can you resolve it. I would like to know how I can set the response from API to the edit text. I mean when we create retrofit requests for each API call then we iterate the response and set it to the edit text. but now how I can get the response and set it to edit text. here is Code i write.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ use this web. just copy your api JSON response and past in the JSON  section. This website will create POJO for you as per the JSON.

Comment: Moreover, for further help you need to ask a new section, but first you need to do effort to solve it at your end.
Happy Coding :-)